# How do I get core tools like Bash, Git and Curl on z/OS?

Tags: bash, git, curl, zos

I'm looking for the recommended approach for how to get core tools like Bash, Git and Curl on z/OS as they are not available on a base z/OS machine.

I'm open to exploring both supported and unsupported versions of these tools.

Answer (score 3):

I know of 3 ways to get core tools, depending on the tools and what you want.
For **unsupported** versions of these tools and more, check out:

- https://zosopentools.github.io/meta/

For a **supported** version of *git*, you can get it from IBM (I couldn't find a great link for this):

- https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/topic/0TO0z0000006v6YGAQ/ibm-support-for-rocket-git-for-zos?language=en_US

For a **supported** version of *git* and a few other tools, you can get it from Rocket:

- https://www.rocketsoftware.com/products/rocket-open-source